# 2 different servers listening to same port and same public IP

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, proxy, port

I am running 2 VMs that they both are listening to ports 80/443. I have just one public IP and several subdomains that are pointing to my public IP. I would like to somehow be able to access both VMs on ports 80/443.

The scenario I have in mind is to somehow involve a third VM which will receive the 80/443 requests from the outside world and redirect them accordingly to the VMs. That third VM it could act as a "Proxy" which will make the requests on the VMs using the local IP which no ports are involved. Im not quite sure if thats possible, but Im open to any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: You could also make the IIS server redirect traffic to the OwnCloud server. It does not need a 3rd server that way. It depends on how many redirections you need and if the IIS server is strong enough. But if I understand the scheme correctly, the OwnCloud is probably hosting files, and not really webpages, in which case this would be perfectly capable through redirection on the IIS server, which can be done from IIS itself.

Comment: I managed to do proxy re directions using IIS. The issue now is my SSL cert.
Previously, I had my SSL setup on apache2. Since IIS Proxy will hit the apache server using the local IP then the SSL Cert will complain.
So the SSL handshake should now be established on the IIS Server. Is that right?
Is there any other way to do it, so I can keep my SSL on my apache Server and somehow passthrough it on IIS? (maybe its a stupid question but I had to ask :))

Comment: Well. I've done that as-well at the end. What I did is to setup HTTP on my owncloud Server and on my IIS setup HTTPS importing my certificate from the Apache. Thanks for your help LPChip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The scenario I have in mind is to somehow involve a third VM which will receive the 80/443 requests from the outside world and redirect them accordingly to the VMs.

You are definitely looking at this the right way. Personally, I would use something like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) to achieve your goal. The actual implementation would be dependent on your needs/environment.

The simplest form would be to use a different set of ports for one server (like 1080/1443) and redirect traffic accordingly. This can be done in almost any proxy server or router/NAT gateway.

Using [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or similar software, you can then get as complicated as you like. Some examples of how you can designate traffic to go to one server or the other:

- URL used in the request (for example requests for /app1/whatever go to server 1, default to server 2)
- Source IP making the request
- File type being requested (all requests for .php files go to server 2)
- User agent making the request (all iPhone traffic goes to server 2)
- Pretty much any other aspect of the headers you care to use
- A combination of any or all of the above

There are many articles and tutorials on using [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) to do many things (including here on multiple [SE](https://stackexchange.com/) sites). For example, here is a simple post about [routing traffic based on URLs](https://linux-tips.com/t/routing-urls-to-different-backends-in-haproxy/24). Or an example on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) that is [based on source IP](https://serverfault.com/a/295093/167012). Google will be your friend when finding examples of what you might do.

I suggest checking the [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html) for everything you can possibly do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is entirely practical and common. One of the terms used to describe what you are doing is "reverse proxy".   There are a few ways to achieve this, including using Apache and Squid.

Because of the way http works, you can't just do it at a (simple/iptables type ) firewall level - you need to intercept the packets to read the header.

Https adds additional complexity, and you might want to consider https externally to http internally - because of the additional overhead and complexities with certs.

The bit on your diagram about DNS is unclear. You would have external DNS, and then use specific rules in the proxy server to map domains to final http(s) server.